# how to maintain variable after random number is chosen

Tags: javascript

EDIT: added full code, done on codepen.io
https://codepen.io/agnizz/pen/aXgdxR?editors=0011
The css is very basic and will be polished when code is done.

My code takes user input. The codes purpose is to guess the users number. Once the number is inputted, you tell the code to guess higher or lower. I'm stuck on the point where it needs to keep guessing to eventually read the users number. Once the "random number" is outputted I need to store that number in one session instead of a different number every time.

I've tried creating a variable for the initial random number so it stays consistent. As code guesses original user input.

```
function getUserNumber(){
  var userNumber = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  alert(generateFirstGuess());
  addButtons();
}
//adding higher and lower buttons 
function addButtons(){
  //guess higher btn
  var breakPoint = document.createElement("BR");
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");     
  var guessHigh = document.createTextNode("Guess Higher"); 
  btn.appendChild(guessHigh);                     
  document.forms["form"].appendChild(btn); 
  btn.setAttribute("id", "higherBtn");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  document.getElementById("higherBtn").addEventListener("click", 
 guessHigher);


  //guess lower button
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");     
  var guessLow = document.createTextNode("Guess Lower"); 
  btn.appendChild(guessLow);                       
  document.forms["form"].appendChild(btn); 
  btn.setAttribute("id", "lowerBtn");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  document.getElementById("lowerBtn").addEventListener("click", 
guessLower);

  //reset button
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var resetBtn = document.createTextNode("Reset");
  btn.appendChild(resetBtn);
  document.forms["form"].appendChild(btn);
  btn.setAttribute("id", "reset");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", 
resetBtnFunction);

}



function resetBtnFunction(){
  document.location.reload(true);
}


//guess higher or lower logic
function guessHighOrLow(min, max){
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  var computerGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + 
min;
  return computerGuess;
}


//Computer generates number from 1-99
function generateFirstGuess(){
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return randomNumber;
}


//computer guesses higher if guess too low

function guessHigher(){
  alert(guessHighOrLow(randomNumber, 100));
}

function guessLower(){
  alert (guessHighOrLow(1, randomNumber));
}
```

I need to find a way to make the computerGuess stay the first variable it initializes.

Comment: Do you mean you want `randomNumber` to remain the same?

Comment: You could put it on a class or make it a global variable that is only modified when the correct answer is guessed?

Comment: are you able to put the full code in your question ? Is this running in node or in the browser ?

Comment: full code added

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the guessed values

```js
// dictionary
const guessDictionary = {};

//guess higher or lower logic
function guessHighOrLow(min, max){
  min = Math.ceil(min); // eg: 40
  max = Math.floor(max); // eg: 99
  
  // generating a unique key for dictionary eg: "40-99"
  const key = [min, max].join('-');
  
  // generates and store computerGuess if not in dictionary
  if(guessDictionary[key] === undefined) {
    guessDictionary[key] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + 
min;
  } 
  
  // always return from dictionary
  return guessDictionary[key];
}


//Computer generates number from 1-99
function generateFirstGuess(){
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return randomNumber;
}


//computer guesses higher if guess too low

function guessHigher(){
  alert(guessHighOrLow(randomNumber, 100));
}

function guessLower(){
  alert (guessHighOrLow(1, randomNumber));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain this line of code please . 

 const key = [min, max].join('-');  -- what is the .join('_) meant to accomplish?